# confusion with adding 2 time values

Tags: php, mysql, time

Basically this whole time stuff is frustrating me, I am new to programming so I do apologise if I am asking a stupid question.

I have a MySQL time() stored in my database. I want to add this time to the current time in order to establish a target time.

$duration is 06:00:00. (MySQL time)

```
$length = strtotime($duration);

    $timestart = time();

    $target = $length + time();

    // merely to check if im getting correct values.

    echo "</br>duration: ".date('G:i:s', $length)."<br/>";
    echo "current time:".date('G:i:s', $timestart)."<br/>";
    echo "target time:".date('G:i:s', $target)."<br/>";
```

Currently I get this out (not 6 hours increase):

duration: 6:00:00
current time:15:51:44
target time:19:51:44

Can somebody please explain this for me.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`strtotime` converts it to a unix time stamp. It DOES NOT represent six hours. It represents 6AM today. You should work with seconds:

```
$duration = '06:00:00';
$duration_array = explode(':', $duration);

$length = ((int)$duration_array[0] * 3600) + ((int)$duration_array[1] * 60) + (int)$duration_array[2];
$target = $length + time();
```

Comment: how do I convert my MySQL time ($duration) into seconds?

Comment: This should work... you get the parts of the duration string and convert them to seconds.

Comment: is that not supposed to be $duration_array[0] etc.. ?

Comment: many thanks! that works great! question for my piece of mind, why when I do this:`echo "</br>duration: ".date('G:i:s', $length)."<br/>";
` is the outcome 07:00:00 ? and not 06:00:00. Many thanks again!

Comment: Because date also expects a unix timestamp. If you use it like this `$length` represents the the number of seconds since 00:00:00 UTC on January 1, 1970. Depending on your server settings any time could be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too familiar with mySql, but perhaps you can try

```
$target = strtotime($length) + time();
```

Answer (score 1):

Strtotime is propagating a date inside there, something like "6PM today", instead of 6 hours like you intend. The easiest way to do this is to run

```
time() + (6 * 3600);
```

Where 6 is hours, and 3600 is the number of seconds in each hour.

Comment: but I need to convert the MySQL time into a format SO it can be added. How do I do this?