# Adding two times together in php

Tags: php, datetime, time

I am looking to add two times together that come from a sql query. Below is my code.

```
$taskID = $row['taskID'];
$startTimeRaw = $row['startTime'];
$endTimeRaw = $row['endTime'];
$everyMinutesRaw = $row['everyMinutes'];
$startTime = $startTimeRaw->format('H:i:s');
$endTime = $endTimeRaw->format('H:i:s');
$everyMinutes = $everyMinutesRaw->format('H:i:s');

#$latestRunTime = $startTime;
$latestRunTimeRaw = $startTime + $everyMinutes;


echo $startTime."<BR>";
echo $everyMinutes."<BR>";
echo $latestRunTime."<BR>";
```

This code returns the following

```
06:05:00
00:15:00
6
```

The third line of the return should be `06:20:00`, how can I make this change. I've played with `strtotime` and `->format()` but none of it seems to get the proper answer. Thoughts?

With the data contained in the other answer I have this

```
$latestRunTime = strtotime($startTime) + strtotime($everyMinutes);
```

And it outputs

```
2733243600
```

If I format that, I get the following

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to change the database query that returns this data? In that case, solve the problem by making the database do the date arithmetic for you.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't in this case. I will use this data to iterate through a loop and write to a new table

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720845/php-add-two-time-variables

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370332/add-two-or-more-time-strings-in-php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5718361/confusion-with-adding-2-time-values

Comment: @mhopkins321 look at the third link you should work with seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be what you're after:

```
<?php
$period = new DatePeriod(
        new DateTime('06:05:00'),
        DateInterval::createFromDateString('15 minutes'),
        new DateTime('07:00:00'));
foreach($period as $interval){
        echo $interval->format('c').PHP_EOL;
}
```

Result:

```
2013-04-22T06:05:00+02:00
2013-04-22T06:20:00+02:00
2013-04-22T06:35:00+02:00
2013-04-22T06:50:00+02:00
```

You could also use `new DateInterval('PT15M')`, or more formally from a time:

```
new DateInterval('PT'.$everyMinutesRaw->format('H\Hi\Ms\S'));
```

If you're not interested in all the intervals but just want the first one as per your example:

```
 $startTimeRaw->add(new DateInterval('PT'.$everyMinutesRaw->format('H\Hi\Ms\S')));
 echo $startTimeRaw->format('H:i:s');
```

Comment: I had considered using dateinterval pretty strongly. The only issue is that with one query from the database, an interger of 90 might come in, signifying every 1.5 hours. And with a different query, it comes in as `01:30:00`. So it is sort of a lose lose for me

Comment: Hm, if those are the only 2 formats, can you just not detect it using `strstr` looking for `:`? The very first thing to do in this scenario is to detect both inputs & convert them to a single usable known quantity.

Comment: Probably? I'm incredibly new to php and my curse of datetimes never working nicely seems to follow me to every language I go to

Comment: And those are the two formats depending on how I query the db. `everyMinutes` is currently stored as an integer

Comment: Well, having multiple formats will do that :P (By all means, let the user enter them however they like, but storing them in 1 predefined format if that's under your control really saves you from some headaches later on). Any way: `$datetime = new DateInterval('PT'.(strstr($string,':')!==false,DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s',$string)->format('H\Hi\Ms\S):$string.'M'));` would do most of the trick here (untested code..).

Comment: Ah, if there are just integers in there signifying minutes, just query them as such, and use `'PT'.$value.'M'` and you're as good as done.

Answer (score 1):

use this function

```
function sum_the_time($time1, $time2) {
  $times = array($time1, $time2);
  $seconds = 0;
  foreach ($times as $time)
  {
    list($hour,$minute,$second) = explode(':', $time);
    $seconds += $hour*3600;
    $seconds += $minute*60;
    $seconds += $second;
  }
  $hours = floor($seconds/3600);
  $seconds -= $hours*3600;
  $minutes  = floor($seconds/60);
  $seconds -= $minutes*60;
  if($seconds < 9)
  {
  $seconds = "0".$seconds;
  }
  if($minutes < 9)
  {
  $minutes = "0".$minutes;
  }
    if($hours < 9)
  {
  $hours = "0".$hours;
  }
  return "{$hours}:{$minutes}:{$seconds}";
}
```

Use this function in every where just call the function when you need..Thanks